# I would like to organize ~2000 subfolders by Country

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders starting with his country name in ISO Alpha-2 (US,GB,etc) i have made a basic bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Folder name:
read country 
mkdir $country 
echo Prefix of folders:
read folder
mv $folder* $country
echo done
```

for organize but is quite exhausting one by one, I'm looking for a way to automatically do this, i guess that i will need a full country list but i don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us the actual subdirectory names and ii) show us the result you want from your example input. You can use the `tree` command to see and share the folder structure here.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to move the folder `GB` to `Great Britain` or `Great Britain` to  `GB`. What do you want to do about space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this for **a dry-run**:

```bash
for d in */
do
    echo mkdir -p "${d:0:2}" && echo mv -n -- "$d" "${d:0:2}"
done
```

Then, **when satisfied with the output**, remove the **two** `echo` commands and run it again to do the real work.

Comment: This is making the trick, looking how to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` command to loop over all subfolders:

```
find . -type d -exec ./myscript.sh {} \;
```

This will pass the name of each folder path as variable `$1` to the script. You can use the `sed` command to extract the relevant parts of the path from `$1`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

country=$( echo $1 | sed -e 's/[^\/]*\/\(..\).*/\1/' )
remainder=$( echo $1 | sed -e 's/[^\/]*\/..\(.*\)/\1/' )

# There must be a remainder.
echo $remainder | grep '.' > /dev/null || exit
# Ignore subdirectories.
echo $remainder | grep '\/' > /dev/null && exit

echo "$1 => $country/$remainder"
mkdir -p $country
mv $1 $country/$remainder
```